# Laravel Routes to wrong directory on Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have just played with Laravel some hours ago and seemed to hit a wall. My nginx document root is `usr/share/nginx/html/`. Inside this folder I have an `index.php` (which shows `phpinfo();`) and a Laravel 4 project unders the folder `helloworld`

In the Laravel `helloworld` project, I have a routes.php like this

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'hello world';
});

Route::get('about', function()
{
    return 'this is about';
});
```

Navigating to `localhost/helloworld/public/` and it dispayed `hello world`, which is correct. However navigating to `localhost/helloworld/public/about`, it displayed the `index.php` in the document root `html` instead of displaying `this is about`

It seems I misconfigured something. This is my nginx [default.conf](https://gist.github.com/hoanglamhuynh/97c094f28a2d4f917aed)

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a root for your server, put this line in your config :

root /usr/share/nginx/html/helloworld/public;

You should not alter the default.conf but create an other file dedicated to your service.